# Как отобразить товары — ошибка «Товаров, соответствующих вашему запросу, не обнаружено.»?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Подскажите, почему могут перестать отображаться товары из woocommerce на сайте?
Пишет «Товаров, соответствующих вашему запросу, не обнаружено.» хотя в woocommerce они есть.
- Видимость товаров — «Каталог и поиск»
- Счетчики товаров в категориях показывают правильные цифры.
- по прямой ссылке товар доступны
- пробовал редактировать functions.php, копировал page.php в woocommerce.php - магазин вообще не отображается, но не уверен, что правильно делал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была связана с плагином ElasticPress. После обновления его и elasticsearch до последних версий товары отображаются.